# Doing something when focus moves off a field

Tags: blackberry, listener, field

I'm new to Blackberry and im currently working on it. I have some fields. I want to listen if the focus is moved off a specific field, say objectChoiceField and then take some actions. Anyone of you know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With existing classes, you can add a [FocusChangeListener](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/FocusChangeListener.html), via [setFocusChangeListener()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Field.html#setFocusListener%28net.rim.device.api.ui.FocusChangeListener%29).  Your listener can take whatever actions you want.

Alternatively, you can override [Field.onUnfocus()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Field.html#onUnfocus%28%29), and the code in the override will be called when your field loses focus.  You can do this with an anonymous subclass, if you only need this once, or you can create a named subclass, and use it repeatedly.